# Having trouble connecting to EC2 instance via SSH

Tags: amazon-ec2

Getting `Permission denied (publickey)` error when connecting to my newly created EC2 instance using the following command:

`ssh console@my-ec2-instance`

**BACKGROUND**

I'm following [this guide](https://medium.com/mint-digital/elixir-deployments-on-aws-ee787aa02a9d).

Near the beginning, it has you [create a stack](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home?region=us-east-1#/stacks/new?stackName=WebStack&templateURL=https:%2F%2Fs3.amazonaws.com%2Fmint.cfn.public%2Fbasic.json) from a template. The second step of stack creation wizard asks you for `SSHPublicKey`.

[image: EC2 Configuration]

I opened my console and typed this:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "email@example.com"
```

This created a "keypair" file and a "keypair.pub" file on C:\Users\Username.ssh.

I opened keypair.pub using a text editor. It looked like this:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAACAQDKMaPD3... email@example.com
```

I copied the encrypted value to the `SSHPublicKey` field of the EC2 configuration shown in the above screenshot.

Then I added the private key file "keypair" to the SSH agent using:

```
ssh-add "C:\Users\Username\.ssh\keypair"
```

I got a confirmation message that said "identity added". I confirmed by typing `ssh-add -l` which lists the identities:

```
λ ssh-add -l
4096 SHA256:TK5SQ7odC9x... C:\Users\Username\.ssh\keypair (RSA)
```

So everything seems to be set up correctly? EC2 instance knows the public key, SSH Agent has the private key. So why am I getting `permission denied (publickey)`?

**UPDATE:**

I've also tried explicitly specifying the private key using the -i flag:

```
ssh -i "C:\Users\Username\keypair" console@my-ec2-instance
```

Same error however.

Comment: This could just be a records propagation delay- I've seen it take 5-10 minutes before it recognizes the newly added ssh-key.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `console` is available as SSH user?

- For Amazon Linux, the user name is `ec2-user`.
- For RHEL, the user name is `ec2-user` or `root`.
- For Ubuntu, the user name is `ubuntu` or `root`.
- For Centos, the user name is `centos`.
- For Fedora, the user name is `ec2-user`.
- For SUSE, the user name is `ec2-user` or `root`.

See also the official AWS EC2 [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html).